# Increase block number on Ganache

Tags: testing, ganache, blocks, block-interval

How can we increase block.number on Ganache for testing purpose ?
If not possible do you know an alternative like passing X fake transactions to artificially increase block.number.

Or if we have to use a private chain: is it possible to change the time between blocks for faster testing ?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase `block.timestamp` (aka `now`):

```
web3.currentProvider.send({method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [numOfSeconds]});
```

Note that this method is a Ganache-extension of the standard.

So do not count on it on other node types (Geth, Parity, etc).

Also note that the code above is valid for web3.js v0.x.

You might need to run it asynchronously in web3.js v1.x.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but I need to use block.number instead of block.timestamp for security reasons. Best regards

Comment: @KevinWad: Well then I guess that you'll have to execute some "dummy" transactions (e.g., add a "dummy" state variable to your contract, and call a function which increments it).

Comment: There's `evm_mine` that can be used to create an empty block and you can use similarly to `evm_increaseTime`.

Comment: @KevinWad: See Ismael's suggestion above.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks very much ! Goodvibration thanks for letting me know !

Comment: Note that this needs a second callback parameter lest it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`

Comment: @PaulBerg: I wrote `Also note that the code above is valid for web3.js v0.x.`. Is your comment valid for this version of web3?

Comment: My web3 version is 1.2.0, what I meant is that you cannot run it asynchronously with promises, but you need a callback.

Comment: @PaulBerg: As far as I know, every function that takes a callback can also be executed with `await` (you might need to import an auxiliary package like `bluebird` or so). In any case, as I stated in my answer (the last two lines), it is compatible with v0.x, while it might be slightly different on v1.x (in particularly with regards to the "async" aspect of executing it).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to goodvibration's answer, OpenZeppelin recently released their [`openzeppelin-test-helpers` package](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers). This library contains all kinds of helpers for testing smart contracts, including methods to increase the block number or timestamp, such as:

```js
async time.advanceBlock()
async time.increase(duration)
async time.increaseTo(target)
```

I haven't used the library myself, but it sounds like it might be useful for you.

Comment: This library looks cool, but note that it breaks compatibility with [BigNumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/), due to several imports that use [BN.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/). For instance, in my case, all tests that had "should.be.bignumber.equal" broke.

Comment: @PaulBerg that's a very good point

Answer (score 4):

I needed a promise-based solution that didn't require installing a third-party library. Copy-pasting from [Ethan Wessel's amazing article on truffle time testing](https://medium.com/fluidity/standing-the-time-of-test-b906fcc374a9):

```
advanceTime = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_increaseTime',
      params: [time],
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      return resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

advanceBlock = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_mine',
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      const newBlockHash = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').hash

      return resolve(newBlockHash)
    })
  })
}

takeSnapshot = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_snapshot',
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }, (err, snapshotId) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      return resolve(snapshotId)
    })
  })
}

revertToSnapShot = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_revert',
      params: [id],
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      return resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

advanceTimeAndBlock = async (time) => {
  await advanceTime(time)
  await advanceBlock()
  return Promise.resolve(web3.eth.getBlock('latest'))
}

module.exports = {
  advanceTime,
  advanceBlock,
  advanceTimeAndBlock,
  takeSnapshot,
  revertToSnapShot
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Rosco Kalis's suggestion of `@openzeppelin/test-helpers`

```bash
npm install --save-dev @openzeppelin/test-helpers
```

My `Node.js` code for contract testing:

```js
const { time } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");
require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers/configure")({
  provider: "http://localhost:7545",
});

async function main() {
  await time.advanceBlock();
  await myTimeRelatedContractMethodCall();
}
main()
```

Further reading : https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#time

Answer (score 1):

With ethers, you can increase the next block timestamp using:

```
await ethers.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [numSecondsToIncreaseBy]);
await ethers.provider.send("evm_mine");
```

or you can choose the next block timestamp as follows (this may be important if you need exact block timestamps, since the above method may result in a timestamp larger than intended, if other blocks are mined before your next contract function call). The new timestamp must be greater than the current block timestamp:

```
  const currTimestamp =
          (await ethers.provider.getBlock(contract.deployTransaction.blockNumber))
          .timestamp;
  await ethers.provider.send("evm_setNextBlockTimestamp", [currTimestamp + 3600]);
  await ethers.provider.send("evm_mine");
```

You can also increase the block number by repeatedly sending an `evm_mine` transaction (but I don't know if there's a way to increase the block number by an arbitrary number of blocks with one call).