# Decrease the time between new blocks in Ethereum Development

Tags: transactions, blockchain, nodes

I'm trying to create a DAPP (with docker-compose) which will require many transactions, and I am currently experiencing nonce problems with my Transaction Manager.

However, I'm not looking for help with this problem. What I would like to do is decrease the time between blocks getting mined in my dev environment. Currently, blocks get mined every 2 minutes, whereas blocks on the ethereum network get mined every 17 seconds or so.

Is it possible to change the time on my local machine in order to simulate a real life environment?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to change the time but you can force block mining using the `evm_mine` method.

```
provider.send({
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'evm_mine',
  }, (e) => {
    if (e) { return reject(e); }
});
```

https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/ethereum-and-clients/ganache-cli/

[How to mine my contract in testrpc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26579/how-to-mine-my-contract-in-testrpc?rq=1)

Comment: or this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/70702/47096 `async time.increase(duration)
async time.increaseTo(target)`

Answer (score 0):

My development workflow and stack goes like this.

1. Remix and JavaScript VM for iteration and superficial testing.
2. Truffle and a single-node private network w. 2 blocks/second to develop unit tests and UI. I do that with Geth and a genesis block that specifies low difficulty.
3. Deploy to Rinkeby with normal block time.

The first two platforms have fast block time. The third one is realistic.

Hope it helps.